# How to create in-app notification alert system in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, flutter-layout

I would like to create a notification alert system like discord in my flutter android project. Which widget or technology should i use to achieve this ?

NB : It should show in any screen currently using while notification comes.

[image: Something like this]

Comment: Look into [`flutter_local_notifications`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flutter_local_notifications  or awesome_notification